# Is it possible to pass a selector or a method signature as a parameter in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

As my title states, I'm wondering if I can pass a method signature or an `@selector` as a parameter? I'm asking because I'm creating a framework and I want to be able to pass instances of a certain class within it a method name.

Comment: Yes. It's in the eBook. You can pass a `Selector` and a closure as parameter.

Comment: "in Xcode"? Not so much. If you mean "in Objective-C", then the answer is "yes". It is also yes if you mean "a block". Method signatures are types. You can't pass types as arguments to a function. In Swift, you can also pass a closure, but not a selector.

Comment: Yes. Passing blocks is usually a much better solution; much easier to use, has type safety, and is much more flexible.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: what eBook are you referring too?

Comment: For frameworks i think delegate-, target-action-, callback-pattern makes more sense.

Comment: Forget my comment - I was mixed up with Swift :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the selector itself of use the name of the method as a string:

```
- (void)myMethod:(SEL)selector
{
   [aClass performSelector:selector];
}
```

or

```
NSString *myMethodName = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(myMethod));
NSLog(@"The name of the method is: %@", myMethodName);
```

Comment: The first one worked! I was thinking about it from a Java Refection pov so the concept of it as a variable completely flew by me haha. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot *not* pass a selector to a method.

In Objective-C, every method gets two implicit arguments, passed as normal parameters: The instance pointer `self` and the target selector `_cmd`. They are present in each and every method. The `_cmd` parameter is of type `SEL`. It is used by the runtime to look up the method implementation (this is the core of objc's dynamism).

You can, of course, add additional parameter of `SEL` type.